# Create a file then add an arbitrary text using fs functions in node js

Tags: node.js, node.js-fs

Is there a reason why this code doesn't work? additionally using node file.js responds MODULE_NOT_FOUND.

```js
const fs = require('fs');

// Create the "text.txt" file with the content "hello world"
fs.writeFileSync('text.txt', 'hello world');

// Add additional text to the end of the file
fs.appendFileSync('text.txt', '\nThis is additional text.');

console.log('Hello, World!');
```

Comment: This code runs successfully. Is there any other code that you've missed to include in the sample?

Comment: How do you execute this code?

Comment: open terminal in vs code: node filename.js
response:
Error: Cannot find module '/path/filename.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1039:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:885:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Comment: You are probably in the wrong directory. Run this command from the directory that holds the filename.js file.